# Unable to deploy Xamarin app on physical iOS device in JetBrains Rider

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, jetbrains-ide, rider

I decided that I want to work on my Xamarin apps in Rider, IDE from JetBrains. I tried to do that yesterday and the problem was, I can't for some reason deploy my app on physical iOS device (iPad 4). In Visual Studio 19 for Mac it works fine, so my provisioning is fine.

When I try to run app with iOS default config, it offers me various deployment targets, all of which are simulators. But if I go to edit the configuration, I can select connected device and then select my iPad. Though, when I go to run the app again, I am once more greeted with list of simulators.

Please, help me figure out what the issue is, brief googling did not help.

Comment: Hey, what project configuration do you have selected?

Comment: @Arseny.Chernyaev I have selected iOS default configuration, when rider is installed, there are only 2 options - Android default and iOS default

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I fixed it by switching from Debug configuration to Debug|Iphone configuration, then it showed my ipad as deployment target. Hope it helps someone